# How to integrate Scala language with Spring Security

Tags: java, security, scala, integration

I'd like to know how to integrate Scala with Spring Security (i.e. Acegi)?  What are best practices and roadblocks while doing the integration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scala interoperates well with Java, so there should be nothing special that you need to do. Follow the instructions that have been written for Java and write equivalent Scala code.